# ElasticSearch Nested types with List Inside the nested type

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, nosql

Is it possible to have a Nested  Type with List inside of it in ElasticSearch? An Example would be something of I was thinking is like this

```
{
  "name" : "Zach",
  "car" : [
    {
      "make" : "Saturn",
      "model" : "SL",
      "colors": ["Red","Blue","Green"]
     },
    {
      "make" : "Saturn",
      "model" : "Imprezza",
      "colors": ["Pink","Green"]
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I query such the FF?

1) I want to query all persons that their cars  are "make" with "Saturn" and has colors of "Green"

2) I want to query all persons that their cars   has colors of "Green" or "PINK"

Comment: So, did it solved your problem or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here's how I would do it:

Step 1. Set up mapping:

```
PUT /index_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "type_name": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "car": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "make": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "model": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "colors": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Step 2. Populate the index:

```
PUT /index_name/type_name/1
{
  "name": "Zach",
  "car": [
    {
      "make": "Saturn",
      "model": "SL",
      "colors": [
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "Green"
      ]
    },
    {
      "make": "Saturn",
      "model": "Imprezza",
      "colors": [
        "Pink",
        "Green"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Step 3. Query the index.
Note: You'll need to use the [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) in order to retrieve documents with multiple query parameters.

```
GET /index_name/type_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "car",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "make": "Saturn"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "colors": "Green"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Question, why  "car.colors.color": "Green" ? why not "car.colors" only?

Comment: Good question. I changed the colors property from an object to an array as described [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-array-type.html). That should simplify things.

Comment: Another question, why did you added an index on colors? "index_name": "tag" ?

Comment: You're right, it's not necessary. I removed it from the answer.

Comment: why didn't also use a nested query when querying nested objects?

Comment: I changed the type of the car object to "nested" and modified the search to a nested query. Now, if you query for a Red SL, you'll get one hit, but if you query for a Pink SL, you won't receive any hits. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: but what if I want to see cars that has the color green or color pink? how do I go about that?

Comment: You would replace "must" with "should" and change the first match query to use the "color" field (just like the second match query). Here's a link to the [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) on the elasticsearch website.

Comment: I'll add a should clause?

Comment: Yes. "must" in elasticsearch is equivalent to a boolean AND, while "should" is equivalent to a boolean OR. ("should":[{"match":{"colors":"Green"}},{"match":{"colors":"Pink"}}])

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can have array of nested documents.

Here is your solution.

Create index, put mapping and data.

```
PUT x3
PUT x3/x4/_mapping
{
   "x4": {
      "properties": {
         "name": {
            "type": "string"
         },
         "car": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
               "make": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "model": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "colors": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /x3/x4/1
{
  "name": "Zach",
  "car": [
    {
      "make": "Saturn",
      "model": "SL",
      "colors": [
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "Green"
      ]
    },
    {
      "make": "Saturn",
      "model": "Imprezza",
      "colors": [
        "Pink",
        "Green"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

1) I want to query all persons that their cars are "make" with "Saturn" and has colors of "Green"

```
POST x3/x4/_search
{
    "filter": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "car",
           "filter": {
               "and": {
                  "filters": [
                     {
                         "term": {
                            "make":"Saturn"
                         }
                     },{
                         "term": {
                            "colors":"Green"
                         }
                     }
                  ]
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

2) I want to query all persons that their cars has colors of "Green" or "PINK"

```
POST x3/x4/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "car",
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
               "car.colors": [
                  "Green" , "Pink"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

References:: [nested filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-filter.html), [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html) , [term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html)

Hope this helps!!